# Issues with pthread_create()

Tags: c, struct, pthreads

So i asked a question earlier about a specific issue. I have looked over other questions on this site but most of them dont deal with my issue particularly though i think this question would be useful to other beginners. So heres the code.

(pi.h) How my struct is laid out

```
#ifndef __PI_TEST_H
#define __PI_TEST_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct piS                  //struct for threading
{
    int threads;  //amount of threads running
    int iterations;  //amount of iterations  
    int operation;  //whether to add or subtract
    double total;   //value of pi
};

double calcPi(int numIter);
void *piPthreads(void *info);

#endif
```

(pi.c) How i place values into struct and calculate pi

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "pi.h"

/***************************************************
 * struct for pthreads
***************************************************/

void *piPthreads(void *arg)
{
    struct piS *threader = (struct piS*) arg;
    int operation = threader->operation;    //rank
    int threads = threader->threads;    //count
    int iterations = threader->iterations / threads;
    double begin = operation * iterations;
    double end = begin + iterations;
    printf("iterations = %d\n",iterations);
    threader->total = 0;
    int plusMinus = 1;

    if((int)begin%2)
        plusMinus = -1;

    double loop = begin;

    printf("begin: %d, end: %d\n",begin, end);

    for(loop = begin;loop < end;loop++)
    {
        if(plusMinus == 1)
        {
            threader->total += (1/(2*loop+1));
            printf("threader->total = %d\n",threader->total);
        }
        else
            {
                threader->total -= (1/(2*loop+1));
                printf("threader->total = %d\n",threader->total);
            }
        } 

        return NULL;
    }
```

(pithreadDriver.c) How i run pthread and how its handled

```
//driver class to run pthread
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "pi.h"


/**********************************************
* main()
* handles command line arguments and passes
* for pThreads
**********************************************/
int main(int argc, char** argv){

    int numIter = 100;
    int pthread = 4;


    //Handle command line args
    if(argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Default:Number of threads being set to 4.\n");
        printf("Default:Number of iterations set to 100.\n");

        if(atoi(argv[2]) > 28)
        {
            printf("Default:Number of threads being set to 4\n");
            printf("Max threads possible 28\n");
            pthread = 4;

        }
            printf("Format for running:( executable   iterations    threads)\n");
    }

    if(argc == 3)
    {
        //Assign args
        numIter = atoi(argv[1]);

        //Assign threads
        pthread = atoi(argv[2]);
    }       

    //creating and handling pthreads
    pthread_t *tids = (pthread_t*) malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * pthread);

    struct piS *threader = (struct piS*) malloc(sizeof(struct piS) * pthread);

    int loop = 0;


    //filling in values for pthreads and creating each thread
    for(loop = 0;loop < pthread;loop++)
    {
        threader[loop].operation = loop;
        threader[loop].threads = pthread;
        threader[loop].iterations = numIter;
        printf("threader[%d].iterations = %d\n",loop,threader[loop].iterations);
        pthread_create(&tids[loop],NULL,piPthreads,&threader);
    }

     double answer = 0;

    for(loop = 0;loop < pthread; loop++)
    {
        pthread_join(tids[loop],NULL);
        answer += threader[loop].total;
        printf("threader[%d] = %d\n",loop,threader[loop].total);
    }

    answer = answer * 4;

    printf("answer is %f using %d iterations\n",answer,numIter);            

    return 0;
}
```

(out.txt) Output when its ran

```
Default:Number of threads being set to 4.
Default:Number of iterations set to 100.
Format for running:( executable   iterations    threads)
threader[0].iterations = 100
threader[1].iterations = 100
threader[2].iterations = 100
iterations = 0
begin: 0, end: 0
threader[3].iterations = 100
iterations = 0
begin: 0, end: 0
threader[0] = 0
threader[1] = 1
iterations = 0
begin: 0, end: 0
iterations = 0
begin: 0, end: 0
threader[2] = 2
threader[3] = 3
answer is 0.000000 using 100 iterations
```

I can see the threads are being ran properly. I can also see why its not going in my for loop to address the actual calculation. Much of this is the code the instructor showed us and it was only really touched on but not gone over. I've tried using print statements inside my pi.c in order to figure out. I can see that the iteration value isnt being placed in properly. From what i get of this code it isnt going to run the way I want it to run. But Im having issues figuring out why my iterations arent being passed through.

Comment: Inside `if(argc == 3)`...you create new variables leaving the outer ones unchanged.

Comment: True ill remove the declaration and just assign the values. Thank you.

Comment: Also, I believe the last parameter to `pthread_create` is wrong. Shouldn't it be `&threader[loop]`?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp dbush helped with explaining it but thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The the fourth parameter you pass to `pthread_create` is `&threader`.  This expression has type `struct piS **` since `threader` has type `struct piS *`.  But in your thread function, you convert the parameter to type `struct piS *`.  These don't match, so you're attempting to treat an object of one type as an object of another type.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You should be passing `&threader[loop]` to `pthread_create` so the types match.

```
pthread_create(&tids[loop],NULL,piPthreads,&threader[loop]);
```

Comment: Thank you. Like i said we got this from our instructor. It took a moment for me to understand how it went to a double pointer. But i read what you stated a few more times. And it made more sense and it passed over the values. Now i just need to work on my logic. Thank you very much.